# How to put API_KEY inside the ".env" file in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, file, environment, api-key, dotenv

I want to put my API key inside the `.env` file within my Flutter application and I did it like following:

```
API_KEY=ewwfwfwe
API_KEY = ewwfwfwe
API_KEY=`ewwfwfwe`
API_KEY = `ewwfwfwe`
```

But none of them works! I don't know what is the problem and which way is the right way doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first one is correct, just make sure you're that in your pubspec.yaml under `assets` you added `.env` then in your main function you have something that looks like this.

```
void main() async {
  await dotenv.load(fileName: ".env");
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Then in the places you want to use the `.env` variables, you call them like this

```
dotenv.env["API_KEY"]!
```

Comment: where does the .env file go?

Comment: Your root folder should sit at the same place you see pubspec.yaml and other supporting flutter files.